# Рекурсия. Написать код, используя рекурсию

Tags: c++

Вычислить произведение двух целых положительных чисел  p = a * b по следующему алгоритму: p = 2 * (a * b / 2) , если b четное; p = a + (a * (b - 1)) , если b  нечетное.

Comment: Ваши попытки прилагаются? в чем состоит проблема? в чем ошибка?

Comment: Проблема в том, что не могу найти примеров рекурсии: есть только примеры для факториалов. Не могу понять принцип использования рекурсии для решения поставленной задачи. 
Без рекурсии сделать данное задание можно очень легко.

Comment: Дело в том что данная задача решается вообще без каких либо вложений, циклов, и рекурсий. Данные вами алгоритмы решают вашу задачу в 1 проход. 
Где вы взяли задачу? или кто вам её дал?

Comment: Это задание для лабораторной работы. Без рекурсии я её решил: 
if (b & 1)          
  {
   cout << "Enter a: ";
   cin >> a;
   p = a + (a * (b - 1));
   cout << p << endl;
  }
  else
  {
   cout << "Enter a: ";
   cin >> a;
   p = 2 * (a * b / 2);
   cout << p << endl;
  }
Но теперь нужно решить её, используя рекурсию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int mul( int a, int b )
{
    if( !b ) return 0;
    if( b%2 ) return a + mul(a,b-1);
    return 2 * mul( a, b/2 );
}

int main()
{
    cout << mul( 5, 3 ) << endl;
}
```

Решение взято с: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread887583.html